# Is it correct to say "which country do you like the most?"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure, definite-article, superlatives

Is it correct to say "which country do you like the most?" or is there any other way to ask this question?

Is it ok to skip 'the' in this question? I heard that one should use 'the' when speaking of superlative but I often see the sentences like 'Which do you like most?'

Answer (score 7):

It's fine with or without *the*.

Some questions, like this one, seem more natural to me with *the*, and others without, but I'm not entirely sure why.

Answer (score 2):

Probably , I am wrong now but I've remembered the following rule from the book - Essential grammar in Use.

> We use a which in questions when we have opportunity to choose a variant.

For example - Which river is the longest - Amazon or Nile.

> But , if there is no opportunity then we shoud use a what.

What is the longest river in the world?

You can also easy say - what is your favourite country? (without most)Favourite means the most ...

Please,using a verb to make your question is a little difficult for me)Choose way that I've gave)

Comment: True that you can replace *which* with *what* here and that would also be fine. But you cannot say “your the most”. Only one of these modifiers can be used at a time. “What is your favo(u)rite country?” Or “What is your most favo(u)rite country?” But I think in this case the *most* is redundant since *favorite* means “most favored.”

Comment: @Mixolydian I'm agree with you.I thought the most is redundant but I was not sure.Thanks for your comment!

Comment: This answer does not address the point that the OP was asking about, which was the use of _most_ vs _the most_.

Comment: I am the questioner and actually i was asking 2 questuons.1)How do you ask other people's favourite country 2)is it ok to skip 'the' when using the word 'most'. So both answers helped me with each question haha thank u!

Comment: @ColinFine , I think you're wrong.There are two questions.The first one has to do with - Is it correct to say - "which country do you like the most"?..And there is continuation - is there any other way to ask this.I've answered these two questions.The question is not only about the use of most vs the most!

Comment: @ColinFine , if you look at H.Kim's comment you'll realize everything.

Comment: @H.Kim You should ask one question per question to avoid confusion like this.